# Magento 2 require Js Component Init: not working

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, requirejs

I am having a problem, while initializing.
If I define those in document.ready it works as expected,but of-course my functions couldn't be called from that scope.

**web/js/shadefinder.js**

```
define([
'jquery',
'underscore',
'mage/template',
'mage/translate',
'mage/url',
'jquery/ui',
'slick'
], function ($, _, mageTemplate, $translate, url) {
'use strict';

var Shadefinder = {

    init: function () {
        var msSfLoader = '.ms-sf-loader';

        var _this = this;
        _this.shade = '';
        _this.skin = '';
        _this.underlyingColor = '';
        _this.desiredFormula = '';
        _this.skinTone = '';
        _this.baseurl = url;
        _this.mediaurl = $('#mediaUrl').val()+'shade_finder/';
        // _this.skinurl = skin;
        _this.currentStep = 0;
        _this.result = '';
        _this.mediaurlshade = $('#mediaUrl').val()+'images/';

        $('ms-sf-step-2', 'ms-sf-step-3', 'ms-sf-step-4', 'ms-sf-step-5', 'final').hide();

        jQuery(document).on('click', '.start-over', function () {
            _this.startOver();
        });

        jQuery(document).on('click', '.skinlabel1', function () {
            _this.nextStep(this, 0);

        });
        jQuery(document).on('click', '.skinlabel2', function () {
            _this.nextStep(this, 0);

        });
        jQuery(document).on('click', '.skinlabel3', function () {
            _this.nextStep(this, 0);

        });
        jQuery(document).on('click', '.skinlabel4', function () {
            _this.nextStep(this, 0);

        });
        jQuery(document).on('click', '.ms-shade-color-title', function () {
            _this.underlyingColor = jQuery(this).attr('value');
        });

        jQuery(document).on('click', '#bulk_add', function () {
            _this.bulkAddToCart(jQuery(this).val());
            jQuery(this).attr('disabled', true);
        });

        jQuery('.ms-shadefinder-logo').on('click', function (e) {
            jQuery(this).addClass('selected');
            jQuery('.ms-shadefinder-overlay').show();
            jQuery('.shadefinder-widget-main').show();
        });

        jQuery('.ms-shadefinder-close').on('click', function (e) {
            jQuery('.ms-shadefinder-overlay, .ms-shadefinder-popup, #ms-sf-step-2, #ms-sf-step-3, #ms-sf-step-4, #ms-sf-step-5, #final').hide();
            jQuery('#ms-sf-step-1').show();
            jQuery('.ms-shadefinder-logo, .shade-box').removeClass('selected');
            jQuery('.shade-box').removeClass('unselected');
        });


        jQuery('.icon_help').on('click', function () {
            jQuery(this).toggleClass('help_selected');
            jQuery('.ms-shadefinder-help').slideToggle();
        });


        jQuery(document).on('click', '#stpcont-4 .shade-box:first-child', function () {
            if (jQuery('#stpcont-4 .shade-box:first-child').hasClass('selected')) {
                jQuery('#step-nav-next-4').html('<span>Finish</span>');
            } else {
                var foundationResultLink = jQuery('#stpcont-4 .shade-box:first-child .ms-foundation-result-finish').attr('href');
                jQuery('#step-nav-next-4').html('<a href=' + foundationResultLink + '><span>Finish</span></a>');
            }
        });

        jQuery(document).on('click', '#stpcont-4 .shade-box:nth-child(2)', function () {
            if (jQuery('#stpcont-4 .shade-box:nth-child(2)').hasClass('selected')) {
                jQuery('#step-nav-next-4').html('<span>Finish</span>');
            } else {
                var foundationResultLink2 = jQuery('#stpcont-4 .shade-box:nth-child(2) .ms-foundation-result-link a').attr('href');
                jQuery('#step-nav-next-4').html('<a href=' + foundationResultLink2 + '><span>Finish</span></a>');
            }
        });

        jQuery(document).on('click', '#step-nav-next-4', function () {
            if (!jQuery('#ms-sf-step-4 .shade-box.selected').hasClass('selected')) {
                jQuery('#ms-sf-step-4 .ms-error-msg').show();
            } else {
                jQuery('#ms-sf-step-4 .ms-error-msg').hide();
            }
        });

        jQuery('#step-nav-next-1').on('click', function () {
            if (jQuery('.ms-shadefinder-step1 .ms-shadefinder-step1-item').hasClass('selected')) {
                jQuery('#ms-sf-step-1 .ms-shadefinder-container2 .ms-error-msg').hide();
                var _this = this;
                jQuery(msSfLoader).show();
                var skintype = jQuery('.ms-shadefinder-step1 .ms-shadefinder-step1-item.selected .skinlabel').text();
                var html = '';
                jQuery('.shade-box-container').empty();
                $.ajax({
                    url: url.build('foundation-shade-finder/index/getSkinToneBySkinType'),
                    type: "GET",
                    data: {skintype: skintype},
                    success: function (response) {
                        var res = response.responseText.evalJSON();
                        if (res.status === 'success') {
                            if (res.content.length) {
                                res.content.each(function (e, i) {
                                    html += e.content;
                                });
                            }
                            jQuery('#ms-sf-step-1').hide();
                            jQuery('#ms-sf-step-2').show();
                            //jQuery('.shade-box-container').html(html).slick("refresh");
                            jQuery('.shade-box-container').html(html);
                            jQuery('.shade-box-container').removeClass("slick-initialized slick-slider");

                            /*var options = {
                                selector: '.shade-box-container',
                                show: 3,
                                scroll: 1,
                                responsive: [3, 2, 1]
                            };*/
                            //$.tam.slider(options);

                            jQuery('.shade-box-container').slick({
                                infinite: false,
                                slidesToShow: 3,
                                slidesToScroll: 1,
                                responsive: [
                                    {
                                        breakpoint: 767,
                                        settings: {
                                            vertical: true,
                                            slidesToShow: 3,
                                            slidesToScroll: 1,
                                            dots: true,
                                            arrows: false
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            });

                            jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 0);
                            jQuery(msSfLoader).hide();
                        } else {
                            jQuery(msSfLoader).hide();
                        }
                    },
                    fail: function (response) {

                    }
                });
            } else {
                jQuery('#ms-sf-step-1 .ms-shadefinder-container2 .ms-error-msg').show();
            }
        });

        jQuery(document).on('click', '#step-nav-back-2', function () {
            jQuery('#ms-sf-step-2').hide();
            jQuery('#ms-sf-step-1').show();
            jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 0);
        });

        jQuery(document).on('click', '.shade-box', function () {
            var stepParentId = '#' + jQuery(this).parents('.stp-cont').attr('id');
            jQuery(this).siblings().removeClass('selected');
            jQuery(this).siblings().addClass('unselected');
            if (jQuery(this).hasClass('selected')) {
                jQuery(this).removeClass('selected');
                jQuery(this).siblings().removeClass('unselected');
            } else {
                jQuery(this).addClass('selected');
                jQuery(this).removeClass('unselected');
            }

            if (jQuery(stepParentId + ' .shade-box.selected').hasClass('selected')) {
                jQuery(stepParentId + ' .ms-error-msg').hide();
                jQuery(stepParentId + ' .ms-shadefinder-step-next').removeClass('ms-shadefinder-item-unselected');
            } else {
                jQuery(stepParentId + ' .ms-error-msg').show();
                jQuery(stepParentId + ' .ms-shadefinder-step-next').addClass('ms-shadefinder-item-unselected');
            }
        });

        jQuery(document).on('click', '#step-nav-next-2', function () {
            if (jQuery('#ms-sf-step-2 .shade-box.selected').hasClass('selected')) {
                jQuery('#ms-sf-step-2 .ms-shadefinder-step-container .ms-error-msg').hide();
                var _this = this;
                jQuery(msSfLoader).show();
                var skintype = jQuery('#ms-sf-step-1 .ms-shadefinder-step1-item.selected .skinlabel').text();
                var skintone = jQuery('#ms-sf-step-2 .shade-box.selected .sf-label').text();
                var html = '';
                $.ajax({
                    url: url.build('foundation-shade-finder/index/getUndertoneBySkinTypeAndSkinTone'),
                    type: "GET",
                    data: {skintype: skintype, skintone: skintone},
                    success: function(response){
                        var res = response.responseText.evalJSON();
                        if(res.status === 'success'){
                            if (res.content.length) {
                                res.content.each(function (e, i) {
                                    html += e.content;
                                });
                            }
                            jQuery('#ms-sf-step-2').hide();
                            jQuery('#ms-sf-step-3').show();
                            jQuery('#ms-sf-step-3 #stpcont-3').html(html);
                            jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 0);
                            jQuery(msSfLoader).hide();
                        }else{
                            jQuery(msSfLoader).hide();
                        }

                    },
                    fail: function(response){

                    }
                });
            } else {
                jQuery('#ms-sf-step-2 .ms-shadefinder-step-container .ms-error-msg').show();
            }
        });

        jQuery(document).on('click', '#step-nav-back-3', function () {
            jQuery('#ms-sf-step-3').hide();
            jQuery('#ms-sf-step-2').show();
            jQuery('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: jQuery(".stp-cont").offset().top
            }, 2000);
        });

        jQuery(document).on('click', '#step-nav-next-3', function () {
            if (jQuery('#ms-sf-step-3 .shade-box.selected').hasClass('selected')) {
                jQuery('#ms-sf-step-3 .ms-shadefinder-step-container .ms-error-msg').hide();
                var _this = this;
                jQuery(msSfLoader).show();
                var skintype = jQuery('#ms-sf-step-1 .ms-shadefinder-step1-item.selected .skinlabel').text();
                var skintone = jQuery('#ms-sf-step-2 .shade-box.selected .sf-label').text();
                var undertone = jQuery('#ms-sf-step-3 .shade-box.selected .ms-shade-color-title').text();
                var html = '';
                var html2 = '';
                $.ajax({
                    url: url.build('foundation-shade-finder/index/getIdealFoundationBySkinTypeAndSkinToneAndUndertone'),
                    type: "GET",
                    data: {skintype: skintype, skintone: skintone, undertone: undertone},
                    success: function(response){
                        var res = response.responseText.evalJSON();
                        if(res.status === 'success'){
                            if (res.content.length) {
                                res.content.each(function (e, i) {
                                    html += '<div class="shade-box ms-shadefinder-ico-item" id="shadeid-' + e.id + '" sf-label="' + e.ideal_fondation + '">';
                                    html += e.content;
                                    html += '<div class="ms-foundation-result-link"><a class="ms-foundation-result-finish" href="' + url + 'foundation-shade-finder/?shadeid=' + e.id + '" class="ms-shadefinder-url" title="' + e.ideal_fondation + '"></a></div>';
                                    html += '</div>';
                                });
                            }
                            jQuery('#ms-sf-step-3').hide();
                            jQuery('#ms-sf-step-4').show();
                            jQuery('#ms-sf-step-4 .step-content .shade-wrap').html(html);
                            jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 0);
                            jQuery(msSfLoader).hide();
                        }else{
                            jQuery(msSfLoader).hide();
                        }

                    },
                    fail: function(response){

                    }
                });
            } else {
                jQuery('#ms-sf-step-3 .ms-shadefinder-step-container .ms-error-msg').show();
            }
        });

        jQuery(document).on('click', '#step-nav-back-4', function () {
            jQuery('#ms-sf-step-4').hide();
            jQuery('#ms-sf-step-3').show();
            jQuery('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: jQuery(".stp-cont").offset().top
            }, 2000);
        });
    },

    startOver: function () {
        this.displayStep(0, 0);
        $$('.selection-text').each(function (e, i) {
            e.innerHTML = '';
        });
        $$('.shade-box').each(function (e, i) {
            e.removeClassName('selected');
        });
        this.currentStep = 0;
        this.result = '';

    },

    getUnderLyingColors: function (shade) {
        var _this = this;
        var html = '';
        $.ajax({
            url: url.build('foundation-shade-finder/index/getUnderlyingColors'),
            type: "GET",
            data: {shade: shade, skin: _this.skin},
            success: function(response){
                var res = response.responseText.evalJSON();
                if(res.status === 'success'){
                    if (res.content.length) {
                        html += '<div class="shade-box"><div class="shade-wrap ms-shade-color-box" style="background-color:#d3b9ab;"><div class="ms-shade-color-title" value="Cool" id="Cool">Cool</div><div class="ms-shade-color-description"><ul><li>Pink, red or blush undertones</li><li>Skin burns easily, rarely tans</li><li>Veins on underside of wrist appear blue/purple</li></ul></div></div></div>';
                        html += '<div class="shade-box"><div class="shade-wrap ms-shade-color-box" style="background-color:#cfb8a4;"><div class="ms-shade-color-title" value="Neutral" id="Neutral">Neutral</div><div class="ms-shade-color-description"><ul><li>Olive, or a mix of warm and cool understones.</li><li>Skin tans well but may burn.</li><li>Veins on underside of wrist appear blue/green</li></ul></div></div></div>';
                        html += '<div class="shade-box"><div class="shade-wrap ms-shade-color-box" style="background-color:#e0c5a2;"><div class="ms-shade-color-title" value="warm"id="warm">Warm</div><div class="ms-shade-color-description"><ul><li>Yellow, peachy understones.</li><li>Skin tans easily</li><li>Veins on underside of wrist appear green</li></ul></div></div></div>';
                    }
                    $('stpcont-3').innerHTML = html;
                    $('ms-sf-step-2', 'ms-sf-step-4').invoke('hide');
                    // set body
                    $('ms-sf-step-2').removeClassName('active');
                    $('ms-sf-step-3').addClassName('active');
                    $('ms-sf-step-3').show();
                    // set header
                    $('step_2').addClassName('active');
                    _this.hideLoader();
                }else{
                    _this.hideLoader();
                }

            },
            fail: function(response){

            }
        });
    },

    displayStep: function (content, header) {
        var _this = this;
        $$('.stp-cont').each(function (e, i) {
            var stepNum = e.readAttribute('step-num');
            if (content === stepNum) {
                e.show();
                e.addClassName('active');
            } else {
                e.hide();
                e.removeClassName('active');
            }
        });
        $$('.steps').each(function (e, i) {
            var stepNum = e.readAttribute('step-num');
            if (header === stepNum) {
                e.addClassName('active');
            } else {
                if (header === 1) {
                    e.removeClassName('active');
                }
            }
        });
    },

    step2: function (ele) {

        var _this = this;
        _this.showLoader();
        var _shade = ele.down('div.sf-label').innerHTML;
        _this.shade = _shade;
        ele.siblings().each(function (e, i) {
            e.removeClassName('selected');
        });
        var underLying = _this.getUnderLyingColors(_this.shade);

        ele.addClassName('selected');
        $('sel_1').innerHTML = _this.shade;

    },

    showLoader: function () {
        $(msSfLoader).show();
    },
    hideLoader: function () {
        $(msSfLoader).hide();
    },
    step3: function (ele) {
        var _this = this;
        var html = '';

        html += '<div class="shade-wrap ms-shadefinder-ico">';
        html += '<div class="shade-box ms-shadefinder-ico-item" sf-label="LUMINOUS, DEWY">';
        html += '<div class="image sf-image shade-image">';
        html += '<img src="' + _this.mediaurlshade + 'icon_luminus-dewy.png' + '" alt="" />';
        html += '</div>';
        html += '<h3><div class = "skinlabel">Luminous, Dewy</div></h3>';
        html += '<p>Healthy, Hydrated Glow</p>';
        html += '<a href="/foundation-shade-finder?id=' + _this.mediaurlshade + '" class="ms-shadefinder-url">Luminous, Dewy</a>';
        html += '</div>';

        html += '<div class="shade-box ms-shadefinder-ico-item" sf-label="NATURAL, SEMI-MATTE">';
        html += '<div class="image sf-image shade-image">';
        html += '<img src="' + _this.mediaurlshade + 'icon_natural-semi-matte.png' + '" alt="" />';
        html += '</div>';
        html += '<h3><div class = "skinlabel">Natural, semi matte</div></h3>';
        html += '<p>Your Skin, Perfected</p>';
        html += '<a href="/foundation-shade-finder?id=' + _this.mediaurlshade + '" class="ms-shadefinder-url">Natural, semi matte</a>';
        html += '</div>';
        html += '</div>';
        $('stpcont-4').innerHTML = html;
        var _this = this;
        _this.showLoader();
        var _color = ele.next(0).innerHTML;
        //_this.underlyingColor = _color;
        ele.siblings().invoke('removeClassName', 'selected');
        ele.addClassName('selected');
        $('sel_2').innerHTML = _this.underlyingColor;
        _this.displayStep(_this.currentStep, _this.currentStep);
        _this.hideLoader();

    },
    step4: function (ele) {
        //console.log('aaaaa');
        var _this = this;
        _this.showLoader();
        ele.siblings().invoke('removeClassName', 'selected');
        ele.addClassName('selected');
        _this.desiredFormula = ele.readAttribute('sf-label');
        $('sel_3').innerHTML = _this.desiredFormula;

        $.ajax({
            url: url.build('foundation-shade-finder/index/getResults'),
            type: "GET",
            data: { skin: _this.skin, underlying_color: _this.underlyingColor, shade: this.shade, desired_formula: _this.desiredFormula },
            success: function(response){
                var res = response.responseText.evalJSON();
                // console.log(response.responseText);
                if(res.status === 'success'){
                    _this.result = res; // update global variable to use further
                    if (res.skin_tone.length > 0) { // check for tone step
                        // display skin tones
                        //alert("test");
                        var html = "";
                        res.skin_tone.each(function (e, i) {
                            html += '<div class="shade-box" sf-label="' + e.label + '">';
                            html += '<div class="sf-image shade-image">' +
                                '<img width="418" height="373" src="' + _this.mediaurl + e.image + '" title="' + e.underlying_color + '" alt="" /></div>';
                            html += '<div class="sf-label skin-tone" style="background-color:">' + e.label + '</div>';
                            html += '</div>';
                        });
                        $('stpcont-5').innerHTML = html;
                        // set body
                        _this.displayStep(4, 3);
                        if (res.skin_tone.length === 1) {
                            jQuery('#stpcont-5 .shade-box').trigger('click');
                        }
                        _this.hideLoader();
                    } else {
                        _this.skinTone = '';
                        _this.showResults(res);
                    }
                }else{
                    _this.hideLoader();
                    jQuery(".ms-error-msg").show();
                }

            },
            fail: function(response){
                _this.currentStep = 2;
            }
        });
    },
    step5: function (ele) {
        var _this = this;
        _this.showLoader();
        var _tone = ele.readAttribute('sf-label');
        _this.skinTone = _tone;
        ele.addClassName('selected');
        $('sel_4').innerHTML = _this.skinTone;
        _this.showResults();
        // update current step counter on final step
        _this.currentStep = 5;
    },
    showResults: function () {
        var _this = this;
        _this.showLoader();
        var res = _this.result;
        if (res.res_items.length > 0) {
            var line = '';

            res.res_items.each(function (e, i) {
                if (e.shade === _this.shade && e.underlying_color === _this.underlyingColor && e.skin_tone === _this.skinTone) {
                    line = e;
                }
            });
            if (line !== '') {
                _this.renderproducts(line);
            } else {
                _this.hideLoader();
            }
        }
    },

    renderproducts: function (line) {
        var _this = this;
        var html = '';
        var child_skus = {
            'foundation': line.foundation.split('||')[2],
            'blush': line.blush.split('||')[2],
            'highlighter': line.highlighter.split('||')[2],
            'concealer': line.concealer.split('||')[2],
            'netural': line.netural_lip.split('||')[2],
            'intense': line.intense_lip.split('||')[2],
            'kit': line.perfection_kit.split('||')[2]
        };
        html += '<div id="products-left" class="product-content-left">';

        var _image = '<img src="' + _this.mediaurl + line.skin_tone_image + '" width="418" height="372" alt=""/>';
        html += '<div class="selected-tone">' +
            '<div class="image">' + _image + '</div> ' +
            '<div class="label">' + _this.skinTone + '</div> ' +
            '</div> ';
        html += '<div class="item kit">' +
            '<div class="product-title">' + line.kit_title + '</div> ' +
            '<div class="product-image"><img src="' + _this.mediaurl + 'temptuairstarterset_web_1.jpg" width="141" height="150" /> </div> ' +
            '<div class="product-info">' +
            '<div class="desc">Kit includes:<br />' + line.kit_description + '</div><div class="price-box"><span class="regular-price"><span class="price">$195 ($230 value)</span></span></div><div class="actions"><button sku_optn="' + line.perfection_kit + '" class="button btn-cart addtocart"><span>Add To Cart</span></button> </div> ' +
            '</div> ' +
            '</div> ';
        html += '</div> <div id="products-right" class="product-content-right">' +
            '<ul class="products-grid">';
        if (line.foundation_sku) {
            var f_image = _this.result.infos.images[child_skus.foundation];
            html += '<li class="item">' +
                '<div class="product-info">' +
                '<div class="product-title">Foundation</div> ' +
                '<div class="option-label">' + line.f_optn_label + '</div> ' +
                '</div> ' +
                '<img src="' + f_image + '" title="Foundation" width="150" height="150" />' +
                '<div class="price-box"><span class="regular-price"><span class="price">$' + _this.result.infos.prices[child_skus.foundation] + '</span></span></div>' +
                '<div class="actions"><button class="button btn-cart addtocart" sku_optn="' + line.foundation + '" type="button"><span>Add To Cart</span></button> </div> ' +
                '</li>';
        }
        html += '</ul>' +
            '<div class="bulk-addtocart-container">' +
            '<input type="checkbox" value="' + line.foundation + '--' + line.blush + '--' + line.highlighter + '" name="bulk_add" id="bulk_add" /><span class="bulk-label desktop">Select to add all 3 items above to cart</span><span class="bulk-label mobile">Select to add all 3 items below to cart</span>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="toggle-container">' +
            '<div class="toggle-header closed">Looking for additional products to complement your skin tone? </div> ' +
            '<div class="toggle-body" style="display: none">' +
            '<div class="left">' +
            '<div class="product-title current" id="head_neutral">Neutral Lip</div> ' +
            '<div class="product-title" id="head_intense">Intense Lip</div> ';
        if (line.concealer !== 'N/A') {
            html += '<div class="product-title" id="head_concealer">Concealer</div> ';
        }

        html += '</ul>' +
            '</div> ' +
            '</div> ' +
            '</div> ' +
            '</div>';
        $('stpcont-final').innerHTML = html;
        _this.displayStep(5, 4);
        _this.hideLoader();

    },

    nextStep: function (ele, step) {
        if (step === 0) {
            this.step0(ele);
        }
        if (step === 1) {
            this.step2(ele);
            this.currentStep = 2;
        } else if (step === 2) {
            this.currentStep = 3;
            this.step3(ele);
        } else if (step === 3) {
            this.currentStep = 4;
            this.step4(ele);
        } else if (step === 4) {
            this.step5(ele);
            //this.currentStep = 4;
        }
    },

};
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So, somehow I figured it out by myself. So from now anyone come here looking for the same issue can look into it :)

I was not returning the variable I created. That is the why phtml was not able to recognize what init and any function would be. It was out of its scope

```
var Shadefinder = {
    init: function() {
        //initialize whatever you want
    }
   //other methods
};

return Shadefinder;
```